# Microsoft APIs authorizations management with App Registration Portal

Tags: azure, adal, azureportal, api-authorization

When I create an application through **[Azure AD admin portal](https://aad.portal.azure.com)**, when I go into "application registrations", I can manage authorizations for several APIs (Graph, SharePoint Online, Skype for Business Online, Power BI, OneNote...)

However, when I create an application using the **[Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)**, it seems only possible to add **Graph API** authorizations (`User.Read`, etc.)

Is it possible to use **Microsoft Application Registration Portal** to manage application access for other APIs than **Graph** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [App Reg Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) is the portal for registering [Azure AD v2.0 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) (combines Microsoft Accounts + Azure AD Accounts behind 1 endpoint). Right now, v2 does not support getting access tokens for web APIs other than graph.

The feature set on v2.0 will continue to expand and in parallel the portal expose these supported features (including other APIs other than graph).